# Menu python extracting an element from the array

Tags: python, arrays, menu, extract

I'm exercising studying from the Josh Cogliati tutorial and I've come to [this page](http://www.python.it/doc/Easytut/easytut-it/node10.html).
I've written the *test.py* example and now I'm trying to write the same exercise, by adding a simple menu that extracts the elements of the list.
How could I do that?

Here's the code:

```
true = 1
false = 0

def get_questions():
    return [["What color is the daytime sky on a clear day?","blue"],\
            ["What is the answer to life, the universe and everything?","42"],\
            ["What is a three letter word for mouse trap?","cat"]]

def check_question(question_and_answer):
    question = question_and_answer[0]
    answer = question_and_answer[1]
    given_answer = raw_input(question)
    if answer == given_answer:
        print "Correct"
        return true
    else:
        print "Incorrect, correct was:",answer
        return false
def run_test(questions):
    if len(questions) == 0:
        print "No questions were given."
        return
    index = 0
    right = 0
    while index < len(questions):
        if check_question(questions[index]):
            right = right + 1
        index = index + 1
    print "You got ",right*100/len(questions),"% right out of",len(questions)

run_test(get_questions())
```

And here's what I've come to, until now:

```
index = 0
menu_item = 0
while menu_item != 4:
print "-------------------"
print "1. Choose question n.1"
print "2. Choose question n.2"
print "3. Choose question n.3"
print "4. Exit"
menu_item = input("Pick an item from the menu: ")
if menu_item == 1:
    question = question_and_answer[0]
    answer = question_and_answer[1]
```

Not so much, I know, but I really don't know how to get it done.
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already know how to slice a list, and the user is giving you a selection of the Nth question in your list of questions, so just slice it there:

```
questions = get_questions()
question, answer = questions[menu_item]
```

Your `while` loop will throw an error, though, if the user selects something outside of the range available (including 4) because it isn't evaluated until the end of the block. You'll want to do something like this isntead:

```
if menu_item > len(questions):
    break
```

Also, a few style pointers:

`True` and `False` are already defined in python so you don't need to do that yourself, and your first `while` loop would be better served with a `for` as

```
 for question in questions:
     if check_question(question):
         right += 1
```

Comment: err, thanks for the answer, but the truth is I didn't get where I have to add the "questions = get_questions()" and "question, answer = questions[menu_item]" lines.